# Trying to create dummy variables for multiple columns

Tags: python

I'm trying to create dummy variables for multiple columns like:

> - Gender (1 = male; 2 = female)
> - Education (1 = graduate school; 2 = university; 3 = high school; 4 = others)
> - Marital status (1 = married; 2 = single; 3 = others)
> - Defaulter (1= Default,0=No Default)

Could someone please advise how to go about it?

Comment: Columns for what?

Comment: Hi Chrisz, Thanks for your response. I'm trying to create dummy variables for the dataset with atleast 10,000 rows to predict the attributes that contribute to creditcard default, so in this case, I've marital status,education,gender and defaulter spread throughout the dataset, i want to create dummy variables for these so python doesn't regard 3 is higher than 2 or 2 is higher than 1. Hope you got what i'm trying to achieve here. Sorry, if i wasn't clear earlier, i am doing a beginner level data science course.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have 'data' like this :

```
    Education         Gender    MarritalStatus
0   graduate school   male      married
1   university        female    single
2   high school       female    other
3   others            male      single
4   university        male      single
```

Then you can use pd.Series.apply() to apply encoding 
for instance

```
def enc_for_gender(x):
if x == 'male':
    return 1
return 2

def enc_for_education(x):
    if x == 'graduate school':
        return 1
    elif x == 'university':
        return 2
    elif x == 'high school':
        return 3
    return 4

data['Gender'].apply(enc_for_gender)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
Name: Gender, dtype: int64
```

Same for Education

```
data['Education'].map(enc_for_education)
```

Result:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    2
Name: Education, dtype: int64
```

Same for others

Comment: Hi Umar,  Thanks for your response. I'm trying to create dummy variables for the dataset with atleast 10,000 rows to predict the attributes that contribute to creditcard default, so in this case, I've marital status,education,gender and defaulter spread throughout the dataset, i want to create dummy variables for these so python doesn't regard 3 is higher than 2 or 2 is higher than 1. Hope you got what i'm trying to achieve here. Sorry, if i wasn't clear earlier, i am doing a beginner level data science course.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the dictionary as key value:

```
Gender= {1: "male",2 : "female"}
Education = {1 :"graduate school", 2 : "university", 3 : "high school", 4 : "others"}
```

Suggest you to use string as key in dict if possible for you then u can use like

```
Gender= {"male":1, "female":2}
```

or make the count as string

```
Gender= {"1": "male","2" : "female"}
```

Comment: Hi Roushan45,  Thanks for your response. I'm trying to create dummy variables for the dataset with atleast 10,000 rows to predict the attributes that contribute to creditcard default, so in this case, I've marital status,education,gender and defaulter spread throughout the dataset, i want to create dummy variables for these so python doesn't regard 3 is higher than 2 or 2 is higher than 1. Hope you got what i'm trying to achieve here. Sorry, if i wasn't clear earlier, i am doing a beginner level data science course.